# Find month from week numbers using lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have this list of dates:

```
library(lubridate)
my.dates = ymd(c("2013-12-14", "2014-01-18", "2014-01-27", "2013-12-13", "2013-12-29", "2013-12-06"))
```

The following `lubridate::week`functions outputs a numeric vector when I convert these dates to week numbers:

```
week(my.dates)
[1] 50  3  4 50 52 49
```

Can I get `lubridate` to output a date ("POSIXct" "POSIXt") object that converts `my.dates` to a week number and year number. So output should be a date object (not a character or numeric vector) formatted something like this:

```
[1] "50-2013" "3-2014"   "4-2014"   "50-2013" "52-2013" "49-2013"
```

I'm specifically interested in a solution that uses `lubridate`.

Comment: I don't think you can do this robustly without also knowing the year for each week number.  Not to mention, weeks can straddle end of month/begin month.  Why are you trying to do this?  Do you someplace have week #s with no additional info?

Comment: I agree with BrodieG.  You cannot change week numbers into months without more information.  You *can* however directly change your original dates into months, if that works for your purposes.

Comment: Please see edited question which takes into account your comments

Comment: Your sample output (last "code" block) looks like a week-month, not week-year. Which do you want?

Comment: sorry need week-year. Question edited

Comment: A week can straddle months so there will be days in two different months that lie within the same week even within a given year so week-year does not uniquely determine a month.  To get a unique month you will need some other constraint such as specifying the first day of the week, say.

Comment: Note that I don't need the output to include months, just week-year. If a week straddles different years, can I specify that week should be placed in the earliest year?

Answer (score 6):

To convert `my.dates` to a week-year character vector try the following where `week` and `year` are lubridate functions:

```
> paste(week(my.dates), year(my.dates), sep = "-")
[1] "50-2013" "3-2014"  "4-2014"  "50-2013" "52-2013" "49-2013"
```

The sample output in the question did not use leading zeros for the week but if leading zeros were desired for the week then:

```
> sprintf("%02d-%d", week(my.dates), year(my.dates))
[1] "50-2013" "03-2014" "04-2014" "50-2013" "52-2013" "49-2013"
```

The above are character representations of week-year and do not uniquely identify a date nor can such a format represent a POSIXt object.